# Change fonts with `chessfss`

Tags: fonts, chess, chessfss

I would like to change font for the chess symbols, but it doesn't work.
I have tried to copy the code on the documentation of `chessfss` but with doesn't work.
Can you help me, please? Herewith, my minimal example. (In the document where this is going to be used I use XeLaTeX).

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessfss}

\begin{document}

\setfigfontfamily{maya}
\setboardfontsize{20pt}
\boardfont
KkQkRrBbNnPp

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select a figurine font you should use `\figfont` not `\boardfont`. But the  pfb-files for maya are not in the enpassant package on CTAN (due to licensing reasons), you would have to create them manually. With e.g. pirat you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessfss}
\pdfmapfile{=chess-enpassant.map} %perhaps needed ...
\begin{document}
{\setfigfontfamily{pirat}
 \figfont
 KQRBNP}

{\setboardfontfamily{pirat}
 \boardfont
 KkQkRrBbNnPp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I confess I haven't understood how the package works properly! I don't want necessarily to use the figurines in maya, but I don't like the default one. By any chance, do you know where is a list of fonts available that I can possibly choose?

Comment: well chessfonts_gallery.pdf  (in the chessfss package) shows all fonts I converted. But I think I didn't add which fonts are on ctan, so you will have to try.